# How to determine influence of two time series with feedback?

Tags: time-series, inference

Say you have two time series, A & B. Each have a mutual effect on the other. To give a real-world example, say that time series A measures an artist's CD sales per month, and time series B is some measure of the artist's "Q" rating. Clearly, increase in A will drive an increase in B, but at the same time, an increase in the Q rating could drive sales higher (or vice-versa). Is there a statistical approach to tackle this problem, or is this more the realm of control systems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [Vector Autoregression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_autoregression).

Answer (score 2):

A more general but less tractable approach is referred to as Vector Arima (VARIMA) which doesn't place restrictions on the model form as Vector Autoregression does (VAR). In both cases , one needs to incorporate exogenous variables and be aware that Pulses, Seasonal Pulses, Local Level Shifts and Local Time trends need to be dealt with via Intervention Detection. As usual with time series care has to be taken to test constany of parameters and error variance over time.